# dojox/app model is not initializing

Tags: dojo, dojox.app

My Config JSON is

```
"stores": {
        "explorerconfig":{
            "type": "dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore",
            "params": {
                "url": "./main/explorer.json"
            }
        }
    },
    "models": {
        "explorerConfig":{
            "modelLoader": "dojox/app/utils/mvcModel",
            "type": "dojox/mvc/EditStoreRefListController",
            "params":{
                "store": {
                    "$ref":"#stores.explorerconfig"
                }
            }
        }
```

And the view as

```
"explorer": {
            "constraint" : "center",
            "controller": "main/explorer",
            "template": "main/explorer.html"

        }
```

But in the view explorer if i call the

```
init: function()
        {
            console.log(this.loadedModels.explorerConfig.store);

        }
```

is not initializing to the JSON what i have given in explorer.json

new to dojo please help on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to have an answer here for future reference, (as discussed on dojo-interest) the problem seems to be that the json data is not a valid format for ItemFileReadStore, see this for details about the valid json format for ItemFileReadStore:
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore.html#id5

Regards,
Ed